What is a callback URL in relation to API (Upwork)
I am an SEO professional and pretty new to APIs but I know some SQL, Python and JavaScript. I write code in Google App Scripts a lot so now that I'm working in Upwork a lot I want to see if I can create a sales pipeline in Gsheets with Upwork API. For a web project they require a callback URL and I'm stuck there, no idea what that would mean in my scenario.
It appears I need to host on my server, is that correct? Or is web project not what I want?
What is a callback URL in relation to an API?
Please help
https://www.upwork.com/developer
https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html
Nothing yet, I'm simply at the stage of requesting an API
enter image description here

When you make a call to an API, the remote site process the call and then answer it.
A callback URL is a page in your server that the remote site will invoke with some parameter for you.
For example, in PHP, you can have something as https:/myserver.com/callback.php
That is a "callback URL" sample. Inside callback.php, you can read the parameters that the remote site sent to you (perhaps using $_REQUEST).
Check this out: What is a callback URL in relation to an API?

this is still way too far over my head. I have my own website so let's say I create a subdomain. Do I need it host it on my CMS? a simple blank page? then what? I already read that other post and it was also still WAAAAY over my head, not simple enough for me to understand :(
